# categorical dataframe using more memory than object

Tags: python, pandas

I am having memory issues applying operations to big dataframes where lot of columns are object or strings + nan. I thought moving to categorical would allow me to reduce ram consumption but my first tests are not in that direction.
My initial dataframe with 45K rows and 18 object columns occupies 9.3Mb. I have created a category dictionary using the unique values found in all these columns and move the columns to categorical using this dictionary. The dataframe has all columns now as category but its now using 55.3Mb!!

How come? Is there any step I can take to reduce memory of the dataframe?

Comment: What's the cardinality of this column? (i.e. if you call nunique() on each column, how many distinct values are in each column?) I ask because columns with high cardinality will not benefit from being turned into categoricals.

Comment: indeed cardinality for some columns is big (11k unique records in 45K rows). The way I thought this would work is as encoding strings into integers therefore using less ram per cell but seems this is not the case :S

Comment: That should still save a little bit of memory. Are you using `deep=True` for both? The memory usage for string might not be including the whole thing.

Comment: what is this for? I don't reckon this parameter

Comment: I mean the `deep=True`  parameter to the `memory_usage()` function. Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html